# Telling sed where exactly to append a string

Tags: bash, sed, append

I am trying to edit a file that looks like this:

```
Separator line of dashes
Letters
Separator line of dashes
aaa
bbb

Separator line of dashes
Numbers
Separator line of dashes
111
222
```

The phrases between the dashes are supposed to be titles of sections.

With sed, I want to add a string like "000" to the "Numbers" section. The output would be:

```
Separator line of dashes
Numbers
Separator line of dashes
000
111
222
```

My question is: How do I tell sed that I want to append "000" as first line of section with title "Numbers"?

I have the following:

```
sed -i '/Numbers/ a\New ACE goes here' myFile
```

With that my line is added right below the title, but I need it actually 2 lines below.

For my future reference, how would it be if I want to tell sed, append this at a particular line number after matching "this line"?

Comment: Have you looked at sed's `N` command to read the next line of input into the pattern space?

Comment: Barmar - Many thanks for your help with editing my post. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Barmar - I read about "N" and saw it in an example, but I am not sure where to put it in my line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/^Numbers/ { N; N; s/^\(.*\)\(\n\)/\1\2000\n/ }' infile
```

When it finds a line that matches `Numbers`, append the next two lines and add the `000` string just after the last newline character.

It yields:

```
Separator line of dashes
Letters
Separator line of dashes
aaa
bbb

Separator line of dashes
Numbers
Separator line of dashes
000
111
222
```

---

**EDIT**: Using `a\` to append the new line without doing substitution, as asked in comments. Now only append the next line (`N`) after the matching `Numbers` because `a\` appends with its own newline.

```
sed '/^Numbers/ { N; a\
000
}' infile
```

It yields same result.

Comment: Cool! One question though: Could it be done appending instead of using substitution?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Is it possible to make it a single line? Would a change in syntax be required?

Comment: @DMS: I don't know. I think that I've seen it somewhere but when I have to use it always do it inside a script and running it with the `-f` switch, not from command line.

Comment: @Berei - I understand. Thanks for helping me out. Your commands do exactly what I needed. I am learning by doing, then even seeing when/where blank spaces or new lines are required or not can be confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

It easier to do with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). When first field matches `Numbers`, print that line, read next one (`getline`), print it and then print your line (`000`). The last `print` is the default for every other line of the input file:

```
awk '$1 ~ /Numbers/ { print; getline; print; print "000"; next } { print }' infile
```

It yields:

```
Separator line of dashes
Letters
Separator line of dashes
aaa
bbb

Separator line of dashes
Numbers
Separator line of dashes
000
111
222
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to scripting and have not yet started with awk. I still need to figure out where the "N" fits in my sed line.